# How do I apply a filter to a specific property in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I found angular filter has `filter: value` but it would search whole string, for instance here is the data

```
$scope.names = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
    {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
    {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
    {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
    {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
    {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
    {name:'Mary',country:'England'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}
  ];
```

I want to only display the names that have the letter 'e' in them. But it's also matching the countries with 'e' in the name.

How to I match to only a specific property in a filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `filter` on single property, by having providing JSON object to filter.

**Markup**

```
Name
<input ng-model="search" type="text"/>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in names | filter: {name: search }">{{item.name}}<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do filters only work with $scope variables, or we could use aliases in them as well? I've used filters, and I've had to use `$scope`.

Comment: @cst1992 I don't exactly got your question, but filter does work on collection(it can work on `$scope`/`controller context` variable where as you are using filter on HTML), If you wanted to make filter working inside controller then it will work on any collection, even if it doesn't available in `$scope` like `$filter('filter')(collection, { prop: myVariable } )`